# How to call dumpNativeHeap api?

Tags: android

I find that there is an API dumpNativeHeap in [android/os/Debug.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/Debug.java) which has its implementation in native. How am i supposed to call this API? I tried calling as `Debug.dumpNativeHeap(fd);` but got an error saying the method does not exists.

Answer (score 0):

dumpNativeHeap is not a public API. Use [dumpHprofData](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#dumpHprofData(java.lang.String)) instead.

Answer (score 0):

As @segfault says, it's not part of the public API. However, if you're just wanting to use it for debugging, you can use reflection to access it. It's not recommended to do this in a production application, though.

```
try {
    Method dumpNativeHeap = Debug.class.getDeclaredMethod("dumpNativeHeap", FileDescriptor.class);
    dumpNativeHeap.setAccessible(true);
    dumpNativeHeap.invoke(null, myFileDescriptor);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    // Shouldn't happen unless the method gets removed in a future API
}
```